# Page Breaks in Table in newWindow

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the button the  triggers print data there are no break. Upon thinking about it's a different window. How can I add that bit of CSS to the new window? Any ideas. Thanks.

Edit: Turns out what was making it break right on the ctrl+p print screen was this which is inside the  tab

```css
table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

```js
function PrintData(){
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("Table");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
  }
```

```html
style=table{page-break-inside:auto}tr{page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:auto}thead{display:table-header-group}tfoot{display:table-footer-group}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set the style property on the object. For example, to apply to your table, you would add:

```
divToPrint.style.pageBreakInside = "auto";
```

You will need to get the tr, thead and tfoot objects and apply the styles you have listed above as well. display is the same and page-break-after is pageBreakAfter.

For table rows, you would do something like:

```
var trs = divToPrint.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
    trs[i].style.pageBreakInside = "avoid";
}
```

Here is an edited version of your example. You need to make the changes before you send the HTML to the new window.

```
function PrintData(){
   var divToPrint = document.getElementById("Table");
   divToPrint.style.pageBreakInside = "auto";
   var nTr = divToPrint.getElementsByTagName('TR')
   for(i=0; i<nTr.length; i++){
      nTr[i].style.pageBreakAfter = 'auto';
      nTr[i].style.pageBreakInside = 'avoid';
   }
   var nTh = divToPrint.getElementsByTagName('tHead');
   for(f=0; f<nTh.length; f++){
      nTh[f].style.display = 'table-header-group'
   }
   var nTf = divToPrint.getElementsByTagName('tFoot');
   for(g=0; g<nTf.length; g++){
      nTf[g].style.display = 'table-header-group'
   }
   newWin = window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}
```

Comment: how can i get all of the trs.  I tried document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('TR').style.pageBreakInside = "auto"; and it returned cannot set property of undefined

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns an array, so you have to loop through with divToPrint.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].style.pageBreakInside, changing the 0 to the loop variable.

Comment: I have put up an example above showing how that would work.

Comment: Try my edit of your function. You should check to see what the output is with divToPrint.outerHTML if its still not working.

Comment: i fixed it I had to move my code to before the newWin.open("")

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote above, along with some other cleanup.

Comment: Just read your edit after fixing it.  I was able to remove the thead, tfoot because if didn't format my table that way